# Having trouble returning more than one value from a function and assigning the returned values in a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that returns two values. I am trying to return the values in an array.

```
export function getSettingsConfig (selectedSetting, formSchema) {
    debugger;
        //gets selected setting config
        fetch(`/ui/settings/${selectedSetting}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': '*/*'
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                //maps config to form schema
                let settingsConfig = response.data;
                let newFormSchema = setNonDefaultFieldValues(settingsConfig, formSchema);
                    return [settingsConfig, newFormSchema]
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                /* Todo - add better error handling here. */
                console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
            })
    };
```

In my `componentDidMount()`, I call the `getSettingsConfig` function and attempt to assign the returned values to an array called `values`.

```
componentDidMount() {
        let general = {};
        let values = [];

        //gets selected setting form schema
        getSettingsForms().then((response) => {
            this.setState({settingsForms: response});
            general = response[this.state.selectedSetting];
        }).then(response => {
            values = getSettingsConfig(this.state.selectedSetting, general);
            console.log(values);
        })
    }
```

When I try `console.log()` this array of returned values to the console, I get `undefined`. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong in my functions? Why aren't the array of values getting returned?

Comment: You try to assign a value in a sync function by a value which comes async

Answer (score 0):

You have to use async await to wait for the promise to be resolved and then use the variable values

Answer (score 0):

You could fix your issue by using `async` and `await`

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let general = {};
    let values = [];

    const response  = await getSettingsForms()

    general = response[this.state.selectedSetting]
    values = getSettingsConfig(this.state.selectedSetting, general)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return the promise in `getSettingsConfig` in order to obtain its results by calling it.

```
// ...
return fetch(`/ui/settings/${selectedSetting}`, {
// ...
```

You must also resolve the promise then :

```
// ...
      getSettingsForms().then((response) => {
          this.setState({settingsForms: response});
          general = response[this.state.selectedSetting];
          // resolve the promise here
          getSettingsConfig(this.state.selectedSetting, general).then((values) => {
            console.log(values);
          });
      });
// ...
```